# Delphi algorithm to solve 4 or 5 parameter logistics equation?

Tags: delphi, curve, curve-fitting

I'm looking for an [Pascal/Delphi] algorithm that can solve a 4 or 5 parameter logistics equation. I've been searching the web for quite a while now and have not been successful in finding an algorithm that works.

For example, 4 parameter logstics;

Y = (A-D)/(1+(x/C)^B)+D

Given a set of coordinates (x,y) I'd need to determine A, B, C, D.
(A = max, B = slope, C = inflection point, D = min)

Any help in the right direction? :(

Comment: How do you want to do the fitting?

Comment: Are you talking about this stuff?
http://www.miraibio.com/blog/2010/08/the-4-parameter-logistic-4pl-nonlinear-regression-model/  Sounds like you need to give us more information, on your method, your sample data, etc.

Comment: Isn't this just a math problem?

Comment: It's a not-fully-specified math problem. You see one equation, you have four unknowns, you have not been told for example, that A is in fact, a sample blank value (average response of instrument to calibration blanks).  The OP is leaving out all the important bits and assuming you can wave your magic wand and Presto, solved.  The equation presented here is not something you use in a vacuum, it's part of an analytical method.  X is an instrument response value, and Y is a calibrated output value in some scientific unit. (X could be microvolts, and Y could be parts per million of mercury).

Comment: If you don't improve this question, I'll vote to close it. It's vague and unanswerable.

Comment: Well, my guess is that a good solution might be least squares or method of moments or likelihood, but it's up to the person asking the question to provide some input

Comment: This is a GOOD question, clear enough if you know a bout about curve fitting: "given a set of X,Y I'd determinate A,B,C,D" - perfectly clear to me. See my solution below. I voted to reopen it. Closing a question just because you do not know the answer is just too quick.

Comment: For those who'd like to know; I'm evaluating the output of an Elisa test, which returns a set of 8 'standards'. In this X = optical density observed by an elisa reader, Y = known concentration (always the same units, for example pg/mL). Besides these standards it will also output a number of results for samples with an unknown concentration (Y) but known optial density (X). So to determine their concentration, I'd like to use either 4PL or 5PL to estimate their concentration.

Comment: @Hanzaplastique You should better update your question with all additional information you put on comments. Perhaps other will reopen it. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use non-linear curve fitting library, e.g. using [Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm).

I've already used [this C open source library](http://joachimwuttke.de/lmfit/index.html), very easy to interface with Delphi (after compilation with BC++ compiler).

This code is based on [standard lmfit](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/idl_html_help/L36.html) well-known implementation of the algorithm, and perfectly resolve 4PL or 5PL equations. I've used this library in high-value biological software, including full validation using [NIST reference material](http://www.oakdaleengr.com/datasets.htm). I can not include the Delphi code here (this is copyrighted) but the C source code is ready to be downloaded above, and easy to work with (just one `.obj` file to include - or make a pure Delphi conversion).

You have several paid libraries around, but I did not find anything better, faster, or more accurate than *lmfit*.

Comment: @Warren; yes I'm talking about exactly that stuff :) I'm looking for an algorithm in preferably Pascal/Delphi to solve A, B, C, D for a given set of points. In my example case I have 8 points (X,Y), and am looking for their values to get a good fit. This in part is a math problem, but more so a programming issue.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I'll have a look at lmfit, it sounds like what might work. Do you happen to know were I could get the Delphi code (it being copyrighted; I wouldn't mind purchasing it).

Comment: I looked at the AlgLib implemenation (http://www.alglib.net/optimization/levenbergmarquardt.php) and am kind-a at a loss what data to provide to what function. It seems that most algorithms prefer a initial guess for A, B, C, D which I can provide: A = min Y of the coordinates in the set, B = -1 (typical behavior of the assay I'm running is a down-slope), D = max Y of the coordinates set, and C = average of A and D.

Comment: @Hanzaplastique The initial parameters should be guessed from the function used. The algorithm will quickly fail in case of invalid initial parameters. The one you provided should be correct. I've used lmfit for Elisa tests also, with great success (via a lot of real data also). ;)

Comment: still haven't found a lmfit for Delphi/Pascal (commercial or free). AlgLib seems to have some functions, but I can't get any of them to produce a "good" A, B, C, D (unlike some of those statistical programs out there). Do you recall where you had seen a Pascal version of lmfit?

Comment: I do not have direct pascal version of lmfit. Just use the C version, and link it as .obj to your executable. This is not difficult, and will perfectly work for Elisa tests.

Comment: I'm going to give that a try. For other readers, I've found that AlgLib (http://www.alglib.net) has a nice library, and Data Master 2003 (http://www.datamaster2003.com) offers some nice functions as well. Unfortunately (probably due to my limited knowledge) I have not gotten either to work for my problem.

Comment: Excellent answer! This is exactly what I was looking for. But unfortunately the link is not working anymore..

Comment: You may try https://github.com/jvail/lmfit.js/tree/master/lmfit-5.1